# Enable/Disable Location Worklight

Tags: geolocation, ibm-mobilefirst

I need to disable/enable location service on button click (IOS & Android). I am using Worklight V6.2. hope there is solution.

Answer (score 1):

For Starting The Location Service use the API

```
WL.Device.StartAcquisition
```

For Stopping The Location Service use the API

```
WL.Device.StopAcquisition
```

[More Info Regarding Start and Stop Acquisition services](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.html%23startAcquisition)

> Note:API are same for IOS/Android/Windows8

Answer (score 0):

Follow this excellent [Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/) for using service..

To start and stop the service create 2 buttons in your xml page,and in java

```
btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Start);
btnStopLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);

btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
               startService(intent);
            }
        }

btnStopLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                 stopService(intent);
            }
         }
```

But its a very lengthy task..Hope you will get some idea on how to achieve this task.All the best..